# Remove asp.net MVC Entity Framework auto-generated Global Uniquie Identifiers?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, guid, asp.net-authentication

I just noticed that in the database for the auto generated ids for the default authentication users table the id is not an integer, it is a very large string.b(GUID)
here is an example:
`a202fc44-7319-499e-80b8-96822f5833c0`

Now all of the delete methods are implemented expecting an integer id and now obviously when it passes through its id. It gives an error.

1> why is it doing the string ids in he first place?
    Is there any benefits in using this for a small scale application?

2> How can I change this to just use a normal auto-incremented int?

It is using code first migrations as it is implemented when I create the project. It just creates the database on the local sql server.

Comment: How is your application set up? Code First? Model First? Also, what have you tried?

Comment: @JigarPatel Care to elaborate on that a lil? I would appreciate it a lot.

Comment: @Zapnologica http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_unique_identifier and also http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.aspx I don't know how your project is setup but I assume it is generating guid as a id.